Intellij Idea build error: NoClassDefFoundError : javax/xml/bind/JAVAXBException
Our company forced me to change to newer Intellij Idea version 2023.1 but I encounter error whenever I try to build our project in Idea:
java: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/xml/bind/JAXBException javax.xml.bind.JAXBException
I use:
java 8u201
apache maven 3.8.5
environmental variables %JAVA_HOME%, %MAVEN_HOME% and their /bin versions in Path are set
Intellij Idea important settings:
Project Settings -> Project: SDK: 8u201 (which is defined as its %JAVA_HOME% path in PlatformSettings->SDKs)
Settings -> Build, Execution, Deployment -> Build Tools -> Maven: Maven home path: %MAVEN_HOME%
Settings -> Build, Execution, Deployment -> Build Tools -> Maven -> Importing: VM options for importer: -Xmx768m, JDK: project JDK
Why I need it working:
I need to run JUnit tests in Intellij which initiates Intellij build automatically and it ends up with the error. So that's why I need the build to work.
I expect issue comes from some Intellij settings or somewhere around Intellij specifically. Also consider please the fact it worked in previous Idea 2022.1.4 without changing the project pom or other project related things.
What I tried:
I tried building project in terminal using mvn clean install and that works.
I tried all three of the magic buttons in the right maven tab in Intellij.
I tried using VM option -XX:+IgnoreUnrecognizedVMOptions from this stack overflow thread:
How to resolve java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/xml/bind/JAXBException
I tried to remove all caches from %LOCALAPPDATA%\JetBrains
I tried Invalidate caches and restart Intellij (checking all relevant checkboxes)
I tried switching JDK from oracle to amazon version
I tried switching maven 3.8.5 to 3.9.6
I tried removing maven folder from disc C (there is a folder sources are imported to)
Intellij Idea build-log: (using portable JDK 8u211, but it looks identical with logs using Correto 8 or JDK 8u401)
2024-05-02 16:36:12,327 [  29086]   INFO - #o.j.j.i.j.JavaBuilder - java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/xml/bind/JAXBException
java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/xml/bind/JAXBException
    at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.api.JavacTaskImpl.invocationHelper(JavacTaskImpl.java:168)
    at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.api.JavacTaskImpl.doCall(JavacTaskImpl.java:100)
    at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.api.JavacTaskImpl.call(JavacTaskImpl.java:94)
    at org.jetbrains.jps.javac.JavacMain.compile(JavacMain.java:239)
    at org.jetbrains.jps.incremental.java.JavaBuilder.lambda$compileJava$2(JavaBuilder.java:524)
    at org.jetbrains.jps.incremental.java.JavaBuilder.invokeJavac(JavaBuilder.java:587)
    at org.jetbrains.jps.incremental.java.JavaBuilder.compileJava(JavaBuilder.java:522)
    at org.jetbrains.jps.incremental.java.JavaBuilder.compile(JavaBuilder.java:366)
    at org.jetbrains.jps.incremental.java.JavaBuilder.doBuild(JavaBuilder.java:291)
    at org.jetbrains.jps.incremental.java.JavaBuilder.build(JavaBuilder.java:245)
    at org.jetbrains.jps.incremental.IncProjectBuilder.runModuleLevelBuilders(IncProjectBuilder.java:1553)
    at org.jetbrains.jps.incremental.IncProjectBuilder.runBuildersForChunk(IncProjectBuilder.java:1183)
    at org.jetbrains.jps.incremental.IncProjectBuilder.buildTargetsChunk(IncProjectBuilder.java:1333)
    at org.jetbrains.jps.incremental.IncProjectBuilder.buildChunkIfAffected(IncProjectBuilder.java:1148)
    at org.jetbrains.jps.incremental.IncProjectBuilder.buildChunks(IncProjectBuilder.java:916)
    at org.jetbrains.jps.incremental.IncProjectBuilder.runBuild(IncProjectBuilder.java:473)
    at org.jetbrains.jps.incremental.IncProjectBuilder.build(IncProjectBuilder.java:196)
    at org.jetbrains.jps.cmdline.BuildRunner.runBuild(BuildRunner.java:150)
    at org.jetbrains.jps.cmdline.BuildSession.runBuild(BuildSession.java:389)
    at org.jetbrains.jps.cmdline.BuildSession.run(BuildSession.java:214)
    at org.jetbrains.jps.cmdline.BuildMain$MyMessageHandler.lambda$channelRead0$0(BuildMain.java:211)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1136)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:635)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:833)
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/xml/bind/JAXBException
    at org.hibernate.jpamodelgen.xml.JpaDescriptorParser.<init>(JpaDescriptorParser.java:77)
    at org.hibernate.jpamodelgen.JPAMetaModelEntityProcessor.init(JPAMetaModelEntityProcessor.java:116)
    at org.jetbrains.jps.javac.APIWrappers$ProcessorWrapper.init(APIWrappers.java:190)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568)
    at org.jetbrains.jps.javac.APIWrappers$1.invoke(APIWrappers.java:362)
    at jdk.proxy2/jdk.proxy2.$Proxy26.init(Unknown Source)
    at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.processing.JavacProcessingEnvironment$ProcessorState.<init>(JavacProcessingEnvironment.java:701)
    at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.processing.JavacProcessingEnvironment$DiscoveredProcessors$ProcessorStateIterator.next(JavacProcessingEnvironment.java:828)
    at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.processing.JavacProcessingEnvironment.discoverAndRunProcs(JavacProcessingEnvironment.java:924)
    at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.processing.JavacProcessingEnvironment$Round.run(JavacProcessingEnvironment.java:1267)
    at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.processing.JavacProcessingEnvironment.doProcessing(JavacProcessingEnvironment.java:1382)
    at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.main.JavaCompiler.processAnnotations(JavaCompiler.java:1234)
    at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.main.JavaCompiler.compile(JavaCompiler.java:916)
    at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.api.JavacTaskImpl.lambda$doCall$0(JavacTaskImpl.java:104)
    at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.api.JavacTaskImpl.invocationHelper(JavacTaskImpl.java:152)
    ... 23 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javax.xml.bind.JAXBException
    at java.base/java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:445)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:587)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:520)
    ... 41 more
2024-05-02 16:36:12,335 [  29094]   INFO - #o.j.j.i.Builder - Dependency analysis found 0 affected files
2024-05-02 16:36:12,341 [  29100]   INFO - #o.j.j.i.j.JavaBuilder - javac 17.0.6 was used to compile [core-connector, aop-utils]
2024-05-02 16:36:12,411 [  29170]   INFO - #o.j.j.c.BuildSession - FilePageCache stats: pageHits=0, pageFastCacheHits=268022, regularPageLoads=355, pageLoadsAboveSizeThreshold=0, pageLoadUs=339434, pageDisposalUs=705, capacityInBytes=524288000, disposedBuffers=355 maxRegisteredFiles=61 maxCacheSizeInBytes=38567936totalSizeCachedBytes=0
2024-05-02 16:36:13,195 [      6]   INFO - #o.j.j.c.BuildMain - ==================================================
2024-05-02 16:36:13,230 [     41]   INFO - #o.j.j.c.BuildMain - Build process started. Classpath: C:/Program Files/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA 2023.1/plugins/java/lib/jps-launcher.jar
2024-05-02 16:36:13,483 [    294]   INFO - #o.j.j.c.BuildMain - Connection to IDE established in 236 ms


I would suggest to upgrade IntelliJ IDEA current version 2024.1.1... also upgrading your JDK most recent JDK 8 .... (https://www.oracle.com/java/technologies/javase/8all-relnotes.html)

Please read How to Ask. You should provide the complete error message. Include what Java version is mentioned in the Maven log.

That's actually now a jakarta API afaik: https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/javax.xml.bind/jaxb-api. You will probably need to add explicit dependencies in pom.xml. Have you got explicit jaxb imports?

@g00se Yes. I have one such import. And bunch of other imports for different modules of the old JAXB runtime (https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.sun.xml.bind/jaxb-impl) if it is important.

I would update to jakarta

@aled I have updated the question with Idea build log. I am struggling to find the maven log (I assume you are asking for one created during the build).

I figured out solution.
There is option in Settings->Build, Execution, Deployment->Compiler->Java Compiler called Use compiler from module target JDK when possible. When I enabled the option build started behave normally.
Issue is solved for me.

Seems that Intellij is not using Maven nor Java 8 for that project, at least the log you shared is not a Maven log and it says it is using Java 17:
2024-05-02 16:36:12,341 [  29100]   INFO - #o.j.j.i.j.JavaBuilder - javac 17.0.6 was used to compile [core-connector, aop-utils]

The error that you have seems typical of using Java 8 JAXB in a JDK 9+: How to resolve java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/xml/bind/JAXBException
Configuring Java 8 for the project should resolve the issue.
